# How to solve this integration?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I want to solve this

$$\int_0^w (b/x)^{a+1} e^{(cx-(b/x)^a)} dx$$

where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are arbitrary positive real numbers.

Do i have to solve it numerically? I have no clue to solve this analitically.
If yes, which numerical integration i should try?

Comment: this integral makes no sense as it is.  You're integrating from 0 to x an equation that has the variable x in it?  That's not logical.

Comment: Sorry..I forgot to use dummy variable..

Comment: it's alright, happens even to the best of us

Comment: It is quite hard to tell for arbitrary $a,b,c,\alpha$, could you narrow the ranges for them?

Comment: $a$ $b$ and $c$ must be a positive real number. Sorry, I misstyped the $a$ symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, one can simplify the integral by
$$
\int_0^w e^{cx - (b/x)^a}\left(\frac{b}{x}\right)^{a+1} dx = 
\begin{vmatrix}
u = \left(\frac{b}{x}\right)^a\\
x = \frac{b}{u^{1/a}}\\
du = -\frac{a}{b}\left(\frac{b}{x}\right)^{a+1}dx
\end{vmatrix} =\\=
\frac{b}{a}\int_{(b/w)^a}^\infty \exp\left(\frac{cb}{u^{1/a}} - u\right) du.
$$
So the problem reduces to the computation of the following integral
($\gamma = (b/w)^a > 0$, $\beta = cb > 0$, $\alpha = 1/a > 0$)
$$
\int_\gamma^\infty \exp\left(\beta u^{-\alpha} - u\right) du = 
\begin{vmatrix}
z = u - \gamma\\
u = z + \gamma\\
dz = du
\end{vmatrix} = \\ =
\int_0^\infty \exp\left(
\beta (z + \gamma)^{-\alpha} - z - \gamma
\right)
dz = e^{-\gamma}
\int_0^\infty \exp\left(
\beta (z + \gamma)^{-\alpha}
\right)e^{-z} dz
$$
To compute the last integral numerically you may try [Gauss-Laguerre quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Laguerre_quadrature).

Answer (score 1):

It might be more clear if you look at a concrete example (ie choose constants for all the constant terms and try to solve).  If you let b=1, c=2, $\alpha =2$, the integral is obviously an integration by parts that gets out of hand, but might be solvable eventually.  I don't know the steps you would take, but using an integral calculator [here](http://www.integral-calculator.com/) I get:

$$ \displaystyle\int {x}^{{-3}}{\mathrm{e}}^{x\left(2{-{x}^{{-3}}}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x =  {-2{\mathrm{e}}^{x}}{-\dfrac{1}{2{x}^{2}}}{-\operatorname{\Gamma}\left({-2},{-x}\right)}+C$$